# Is it possible to find the sum of values on one row sqlite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, sum

If I have data in a table with integers like the example below, is it possible to calculate for each row the sum of several columns and output that sum as well as several other columns through an sqlite query command?

My table looks like this below

```
|Timestamp     |Email                      |Name      |Year|Make    |Model    |Car_ID|Judge_ID|Judge_Name|Racer_Turbo|Racer_Supercharged|Racer_Performance|Racer_Horsepower|Car_Overall|Engine_Modifications|Engine_Performance|Engine_Chrome|Engine_Detailing|Engine_Cleanliness|Body_Frame_Undercarriage|Body_Frame_Suspension|Body_Frame_Chrome|Body_Frame_Detailing|Body_Frame_Cleanliness|Mods_Paint|Mods_Body|Mods_Wrap|Mods_Rims|Mods_Interior|Mods_Other|Mods_ICE|Mods_Aftermarket|Mods_WIP|Mods_Overall|
|--------------|---------------------------|----------|----|--------|---------|------|--------|----------|-----------|------------------|-----------------|----------------|-----------|--------------------|------------------|-------------|----------------|------------------|------------------------|---------------------|-----------------|--------------------|----------------------|----------|---------|---------|---------|-------------|----------|--------|----------------|--------|------------|
|8/5/2018 14:10|honoland13@japanpost.jp    |Hernando  |2015|Acura   |TLX      |48    |J04     |Bob       |0          |0                 |2                |2               |4          |4                   |0                 |2            |4               |4                 |2                       |4                    |2                |2                   |2                     |2         |2        |0        |4        |4            |4         |6       |2               |0       |4           |
|8/5/2018 15:11|nlighterness2q@umn.edu     |Noel      |2015|Jeep    |Wrangler |124   |J02     |Carl      |0          |6                 |4                |2               |4          |6                   |6                 |4            |4               |4                 |6                       |6                    |6                |6                   |6                     |4         |6        |6        |6        |6            |6         |4       |6               |4       |6           |
|8/5/2018 17:10|eguest47@microsoft.com     |Edan      |2015|Lexus   |Is250    |222   |J05     |Adrian    |0          |0                 |0                |0               |0          |0                   |0                 |0            |6               |6                 |6                       |0                    |0                |6                   |6                     |6         |0        |0        |0        |0            |0         |0       |0               |0       |4           |
|8/5/2018 17:34|hchilley40@fema.gov        |Hieronymus|1993|Honda   |Civic eG |207   |J06     |Aaron     |0          |0                 |2                |2               |2          |2                   |2                 |2            |0               |4                 |2                       |2                    |2                |2                   |2                     |2         |4        |2        |2        |0            |0         |0       |2               |2       |0           |
|8/5/2018 14:30|nnowick3d@tuttocitta.it    |Nickolas  |2016|Ford    |Mystang  |167   |J02     |Carl      |0          |0                 |2                |2               |0          |2                   |2                 |0            |0               |0                 |0                       |2                    |0                |2                   |2                     |2         |0        |0        |2        |0            |0         |0       |0               |0       |2           |
|8/5/2018 16:12|mdearl39@amazon.co.uk      |Martin    |2013|Hyundai |Gen coupe|159   |J04     |Bob       |0          |0                 |2                |0               |0          |0                   |2                 |0            |0               |0                 |0                       |2                    |0                |2                   |2                     |0         |2        |0        |2        |0            |0         |0       |0               |0       |0           |
```

How can I find the sum from column 10 to 34 for each row, then output each row up to column 7 followed by a column with the total for each row? So far I've only figured out how to get the sum for each column individually but not to across several columns for each row and to output each the desired columns.

```
SELECT Car_ID, Year, Make, Model, SUM(Mods_ICE) FROM Carstable
```

But this only outputs data for one row at the bottom of the table with the sum. Expected outcome would be something like below

```
|Car_ID|Year  |Make  |Model    |Total  |
|------|------|------|---------|-------|
|48    |2015  |Acura |TLX      |89     |
|22    |2015  |Chevy |Camaro   |101    |
|19    |2006  |Ford  |Mustang  |55     |
|101   |2011  |Subaru|WRX      |91     |
```

Comment: Can you include the exact output you expect based on this 6-record sample table?

Comment: An expession for the sum within a row is `Racer_Turbo + Racer_Supercharged +Racer_Performance +..` . No shorter syntax is supported.

Comment: I added the expected output @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sum of columns in a single row you need no extra function like `SUM`. Use `+` oerator:

```
SELECT column10 + ... + column34 FROM Carstable
```